# Internet Explorer 9 and above, deletes text

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

So I'm making a web application using asp.net.

It works fine on Chrome but when I use Internet Explorer 9+ every element that has more than one word (space between words) disappears.

I used this but didn't work.

```
< meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=Edge" />
```

**Normal:**

[image: normal:]

**IE:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us example?

Comment: Try this.

    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />`

Comment: same problem, it only works when i use this   < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> but i don't prefer to use it, i mean what if the user has ie7 will it still work normally?